# Why am I getting Invalid Write (Valgrind) with memcpy()?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

I have three arrays of type `Vector**`: `vectors`, `vectors_left` and `vectors_right`. I'm trying to assign values from `vectors` in order to split it into this two arrays.
**Valgrind** says that the **Invalid Write** is at `memcpy()` lines.

I've tried different combinations removing the `&` and adding `*` to the `sizeof()` argument.

```
  int count_left = count / 2;
  int count_right = is_even(count) ? (count / 2) : (count / 2) + 1;
  Vector** vectors_left = malloc(sizeof(Vector*) * count_left);
  Vector** vectors_right = malloc(sizeof(Vector*) * count_right);

  for (int u = 0; u < count; u++)
  {
      if (u < count_right - 1) {
          memcpy(&vectors_left[u], &vectors[u], sizeof(Vector));
      } else {
          memcpy(&vectors_right[u - count_right + 1], &vectors[u], sizeof(Vector));
      }
  }
```

My code works fine, but I'm getting this kind of leaks.

Comment: You have not allocated memory for the vectors.

Comment: You callocated memory for `vectors_left` and `vectors_right`, but you didn't allocate any memory for the arrays that they point to, `vectors_left[u]` and `vectors_right[u]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the vectors that you're copying into.

You also shouldn't take the address of `vectors_left[u]`. `vectors_left` is an array of pointers, so `vectors_left[u]` is a pointer.

```
  for (int u = 0; u < count; u++)
  {
      if (u < count_right - 1) {
          vectors_left[u] = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
          memcpy(vectors_left[u], &vectors[u], sizeof(Vector));
      } else {
          vectors_right[u - count_right + 1] = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
          memcpy(vectors_right[u - count_right + 1], &vectors[u], sizeof(Vector));
      }
  }
```

Without seeing the declaration of `vectors`, I don't know if `&vectors[u]` is right or wrong.

I also wouldn't do this as a loop with an `if` statement, I'd do it as two loops, since there's no overlap between the two cases.

```
for (int u = 0; u < count_right - 1; u++) {
    vectors_left[u] = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    memcpy(vectors_left[u], &vectors[u], sizeof(Vector));
}
for (int u = count_right - 1; u < count; u++) {
    vectors_right[u - count_right + 1] = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    memcpy(vectors_right[u - count_right + 1], &vectors[u], sizeof(Vector));
}
```